# How to stop user login in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, error, redirect

I want to stop user login in Magento 2 for some customers.
So I created a back-end setting for customers to be blocked by the website and successfully get it done.

But on the front end part, it is not working as expected using the observer.

Like my di.xml file path Tnbl/Blockemail/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="tnbl_check_customer_login" type="Tnbl\Blockemail\Plugin\CheckCustomerLoginPermission" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>

</config>
```

My observer file Tnbl/Blockemail/Plugin/CheckCustomerLoginPermission.php

```
<?php

 namespace Tnbl\Blockemail\Plugin;

 class CheckCustomerLoginPermission
{   
protected $_customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject)
{
    die('aaaaaaaaaaaaa');
}
}
```

I want to show the error and just reload the login page if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't run the plugin on execute function of the controller. Instead, I would probably have a plugin on `beforeAuthenticate` which is fired within the execute method. I would recommend that when your conditions are met, you throw an Exception and let Magento handle the message delivery and events of a failed login.

If you look in the LoginPost controller's execute method, you will see a line that contains `$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);`. That `authenticate` method is where I'd set my plugin to listen to. This is also helpful in the case that the customer is logging in via another means and not specifically the LoginPost controller.

Also, another helpful way to see what's wrong is to move your di.xml file out of the "frontend" directory and instead run it globally. If your login takes place via API call, for example, it may be occurring in the `webapi_rest` area instead of the `frontend` area. Anyways, if you move the plugin to the global di.xml and it still doesn't work after clearing your config cache, something else is wrong.

Also, you don't have an observer file there. You have a plugin class.

Another tip, you don't need `sortOrder="10" disabled="false"`. Those are default values for plugins so they are unnecessary. They arent hurting anything, they're just not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @shawn
I have move my di.xml to Tnbl/Blockemail/etc/di.xml and again try that but the issue is when i login the page it will show the die which i have placed which is correct but when i came back and login again it's just reload the page and not working so basically its just working only one time can u provide some imputs or you have created any module like same it will be really helpfull.